# How to Retrieve rcor and rcov from a result of dccfit (rmgarch package)

Tags: r

i had done a dcc garch fitting which give me a `dcc.fit.ret.fin` object

now plotting is done by

```
plot(dcc.fit.ret.fin)

Make a plot selection (or 0 to exit): 
1:   Conditional Mean (vs Realized Returns)
2:   Conditional Sigma (vs Realized Absolute Returns)
3:   Conditional Covariance
4:   Conditional Correlation
5:   EW Portfolio Plot with conditional density VaR limits

Selection: 3
```

gives this plot

[image: conditional return]

my dcc model is a multivariate model series and this plot only deal with series 1 and series 2 of my model, how am i supposed to get a plot which show my series 'i' with series 'j'?

Comment: What package and functions are you using to get your object? Can you provide [code that can reproduce the object and the graph](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)?

Comment: the package is `rmgarch` while for reproducing the problem you may look at faculty.washington.edu/ezivot/econ589/econ589multivariateGarch.r‎ but on this link the dcc model only contain 2 series

Comment: nevermind apparently i can use this 'plot(dcc.fit.ret.fin, which=3, series=c(3,4))`